Is it permissible to despise hateful and wicked people?
By hateful and wicked people, I am referring to the likes of antisemites, extremist/terrorists, and hardcore, militant atheists. Please provide sources.

In Sefer Chofetz Chaim, Hilchos Lashon Hara Klal 8 Seif 5, we learn:

The prohibition of lashon hara applies only to a person whom the
Torah still considers part of your nation.  That means, one who is
"with you" in Torah and mitzvos.  However, as regards those people
whom you recognize to be apikorsim, it is a mitzvah to deride them
and shame them whether in their presence or in their absence, with
anything you see them doing or hear about them.  For the verse says
(Vayikra 25:17) 'A man should not oppress his fellow" and (Vayikta
19:16) "Do not go about as a talebearer amongst your nation."  And
these people are not in this category (i.e. "your fellow" and "your
nation"), for they do not act in the ways of your nation.  And it says
(Tehillim 139:21) "Do I not hate those that stir up hatred against
You, Hashem, and fight against those that quarrel with You?"  An
apikoris is one that denies Torah and prophecy in Israel, whether he denies the Written Torah or the Oral Torah.  Even if he says that the
entire Torah is from Hashem except for one verse or one kal v'chomer
or one gezeirah shavah or one derivation, he is in this category.

In Shaarei Teshuva 3:148 we learn:

The verse says (Mishlei 27:21) "There is a purifier for silver and a
boiling pot for gold, and a man according to his enthusiastic praise."
This means that a man's qualities may be judged by what he praises.
If he praises righteous deeds and men of wisdom and righteousness, you
can know that he is himself a good man, and the root of righteousness
is within him.  For he only wishes to praise goodness and good men and
to deride sins and humiliate the sinners.  Therefore you know his
quality even before you see him refuse to sin and choose good.  And
even if he has some hidden sins, he still loves righteousness, and he
is among the congregation of those that honor Hashem.  But someone
that praises despicable acts or praises the wicked--he is an
absolutely evil person, and one that defiles the worship of Hashem,
may He be praised.

In Sefer Orchot Tzaddikim, Shaar HaSinah, we learn:

There is hatred which is a mitzvah.  Namely, hatred against a wicked
person that refuses to accept rebuke, as it says (Mishlei 8:13)
"Hatred of the evil is the fear of Hashem."  And another verse says
(Tehillim 139:21-22) "Do I not hate those that stir up hatred against
You, Hashem?  And I quarrel with those that fight against You.  I hate
them with the utmost hatred, they are my enemies."  And he should hate
falsehood and deceit.  The bottom line is that he should hate
everything that distances him from the love of the Creator, as it says
(Tehillim 119:128) "I hated every false path."  This is a major
rule--a man must hate every false thing.  And the more he hates
falsehood, the more he increases his love for Torah, as it says
(Tehillim 119:163) "I hated falsehood and despised it, I loved Your
Torah."  And he should love truth and peace, as it says (Zechariah
8:19) "And they loved truth and peace."


Hatred of people is one of the things that removes a person from the world (Avot 2:11), although as far as I know no precise guidelines are given for when hatred of people in general is permitted or forbidden. But for a Jew to hate a fellow Jew is explicitly a violation of a Torah prohibition (Vayyikra 19:17). It would be permitted (or possibly a mitzva) to hate only in the circumstance that the hater personally witnesses the hated person committing a sin, or if the fact that the person committed the sin is established by the testimony of two witnesses (Pesachim 113b).
According to Sefer Charedim (mitzvot ase midivrei kabbala umidivrei sofrim 1:24, quoted in Tanya chapter 32), another precondition of hating is rebuking the sinner in a pleasant way and the sinner refusing to accept the rebuke (apparently this alone could eliminate most cases where it would be permitted to hate, since there might be no ability to rebuke at all in a generation; see Arachin 16b).

The Talmud says says that the Second Temple was destroyed because "senseless hatred" prevailed in Israel [שנאת חנם sin'at chinam].  Rashi says that it is hatred of people who have not committed any action justifying the hatred. [Rashi on Shabbat 32b]
It says not just "hatred", but "senseless hatred".  This implied that some hatred makes sense.  When does hatred make sense?  The Talmud answers: You may bear ill will towards someone if you witnessed him engaging in an act forbidden by the Torah. [Pesaḥim 113b]  However, you must assist him quickly, before assisting those you love [so that the ill will does not turn to hatred.] [Bava Metzia 32b] Now, how do you know that you have reached the point of hatred?  The Talmud answers:  A hater [שונא soné] is someone who does not speak to his fellow for three days because of enmity between them. [Sanhedrin 27b]

As the old saying goes: to err is human, to forgive divine.
All human life is sacred, for we are made in the image of God. To kill another human is an offense worthy of death (Genesis 9:6), and still God required the establishment of Cities of Refuge so as to show mercy to those who shed blood unintentionally - and even let them return home after the death of the High Priest (Numbers 35:25).
Similarly, Cain was shown mercy and exiled after killing righteous Abel. God even granted him a mark to protect him (Genesis 4:9-15).
As seen in Numbers 35, someone who killed another unlawfully could escape to a City of Refuge (providing protection from the avenger of blood) and they would be put on trial. If the killer was determined to be a murderer, then they were to be put to death. However, if not then they were to be exiled to the City of Refuge. The distinction between these two fates (excepting the case of insufficient testimony) is the presence or absence of malicious intent on the part of the killer.
In other words, what makes a murderer is not the act of killing itself but rather what is in the heart: To hate is to murder.
So then, those groups who spread hate for others are certainly guilty of sin that leads to death - but we are not then justified in hating them; for then we condemn ourselves on the same grounds and become hypocrites. Even when people are guilty of sin that calls for death, the LORD does not rejoice in their destruction. Neither then should we rejoice in the suffering of our enemies.
Proverbs 24:17-18

Do not rejoice when your enemy falls,
And do not let your heart rejoice when he stumbles,
Otherwise, the Lord will see and be displeased,
And turn His anger away from him.

Let us remember that King David committed murder, and yet the LORD forgave him (though there were still consequences). Although the Law does not provide any means of redemption for a murderer - demanding they be put to death - yet the LORD can still choose to forgive.
Mercy is greater than justice

So, when G-d says that He hated Esau in Malachi 1:3, what does this means? And what about those times when G-d commanded the Nation of Israel to wipe out their enemies who were nothing short of wicked and hateful?

The passage is speaking of how God has treated different peoples - the descendants of Jacob vs Esau. For God decided to fulfill his Covenant through Jacob rather his older brother Esau. It’s hyperbolic language used to emphasize all the good God has done for Israel. Of course, there is no favoritism with God - but he repays people accordingly to their deeds. Thus even God’s Holy People often find themselves in a crisis throughout the scriptures. On the other hand, a prostitute like Rahab who otherwise would have been destroyed along with her city saved her household through her actions.

The situation is the same for all those people that God told Israel to destroy: it was through their sinful ways that they designated themselves for destruction. It was a matter of justice. However, even amidst this justice mercy was shown. In addition to Rahab, others were spared - even though the original intent was to destroy all the people in the land. For example: Judges 1:25. On the other hand, God was ready to destroy Israel for their sin against Him with the Golden Calf. Moses interceded so they weren’t immediately destroyed - but God still actively got rid of them overtime.

So then we see that God’s Holy People can condemn themselves through their actions while those of other nations that were condemned for destruction could save themselves through their actions. God is ready to show mercy to those whom were previously designated for destruction when they change their ways, just as he is ready to curse his own Holy People when they fall away

Nice. So… what’s the answer to the OP’s question?

@Qwertrl In the strictest sense, I think it is Lawful to hate someone who deserves it due to sin. The avenger of blood arguably hates the manslaughterer since he seeks his death, and does not sin by doing so. There are also many passages about hating sin in general or people who commit specific sins in the Tanakh. However, divorce is also lawful and yet we know that scripture says that God hates divorce (Malachi 2:16). So we should not say that because something is permissible under (or even required by) the Law  that that therefore reflects what God truly wants from us.

This is why, in my opinion, it is so important to pay attention to the ways in which God "breaks" the Law - overriding it to show mercy and to care for us. Both the Law and Justice are necessary and good and holy. But if meeting out Justice was God's primary concern then we'd all be dead. He certainly wouldn't have let Moses dissuade him from wiping out Israel during the Golden Calf incident or the other many times Israel tested the LORD in the wilderness. King David certainly should have been put to death. etc. So we must understand that the Law and Justice are subservient to God's true will.

In short: YES it is permissible to hate under particular conditions - and in the case of antisemitism and racism generally, one is probably justified in hating one who hates them. An eye for an eye as it were. And there are even situations where the Law even arguably requires hate, depending upon how that term is understood. However, NO I do not believe that hating your fellow man is what God truly desires for us - ever.
